# aws lambda: sandboxed user needs to move executables to /usr/bin

Tags: python, linux, selenium, aws-lambda

so I have a bunch of executables that needs to be in /usr/bin for my python script to run properly, however as the aws lambda runtime environment doesn't give you root access, I can't simply copy or set symbolic links. I'm trying to run a headless python selenium test on lambda

Comment: Do they have to be in /usr/bin or is $PATH maybe sufficient?